# C# - How are we supposed to implement default(T) in Interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Put `default(T)` in an interface.  <strike>Explicitly</strike> implement the interface.  The result does not compile

```
public interface IWhatever<T>
{
   List<T> Foo(T BarObject = default(T));
}

public class ConcreteWhatever: IWhatever<ConcreteWhatever>
{
    List<ConcreteWhatever> Foo(ConcreteWhatever BarObject = default(T)) {}
}
```

I fully expect `default(ConcreteWhatever)`.  What I get is `default(T)` which results in a compilation error.

I just go in and replace `default(T)` with `null` and things are fine.  But this is hideous.  Why is this happening?

Comment: BTW - This is a (minor) refactoring bug - I filed it on connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686094/implement-interface-refactoring-of-generic-interface-improperly-handles-optional-arguments-in-c

Comment: you don't add `public` as a modifier for `Foo` definition. Public is implied because your interface is public.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have a `T` in this case, because `ConcreteWherever` isn't a generic type.

If you want `default(ConcreteWhatever)` then that's the code you should write.

Are you just complaining about the code auto-generated by Visual Studio? If so, that's a reasonable complaint, but it would be worth being explicit about it... (Note that you're *not* using explicit interface implementation here - otherwise it would be declared as `IWhatever<ConcreteWhatever>.Foo`. You don't really have properly implicit implementation either, as otherwise it should be public...)

EDIT: I've just tried the same thing myself, and seen the same result, except the method is made public. Looks like it's just a fault with Visual Studio - I suggest you create a [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) request for it. It's a *relatively* rare situation though, I suspect - creating a generic interface which specifies an optional parameter which uses the default value of a type parameter as the value...

Comment: I use this interface "layout" (if you will) for CRUD operations for Models in MVC.  So at least for me it is a common issue. +1  Thank you.

Comment: FYI - I'd say this is a fairly minor bug, but I filed this on connect here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/686094/implement-interface-refactoring-of-generic-interface-improperly-handles-optional-arguments-in-c

Comment: @Reed Copsey - Thanks Reed you saved me some time.

Comment: @Reed: Have added a comment to it.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this line:

```
List<ConcreteWhatever> Foo(ConcreteWhatever BarObject = default(T)) {}
```

be:

```
List<ConcreteWhatever> Foo(ConcreteWhatever BarObject = default(ConcreteWhatever)) {}
```

Comment: Yes. That's the point of my OP.  That is not what Visual Studio generates.  There's just a `T`when you implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IWhatever<T>
{
    List<T> Foo(T BarObject = default(T));
}

public class ConcreteWhatever : IWhatever<ConcreteWhatever>
{
    public List<ConcreteWhatever> Foo(ConcreteWhatever BarObject = default(ConcreteWhatever))
    {
        return null; // replace with proper code
    }
}
```